# Difference between isEmpty(value) and Trim(value) = ""

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vb i don't get the difference between these 2 statements:

`isEmpty(value)`

and

`Trim(value) = ""`

Can you explain it? Are they equals?

edit:

i have a code like this in my example

```
if isempty(request.form("alias")) then

...

elseif trim(request.form("alias")) = "" then

...

end if
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` is a VBA function; its not part of the .NET `VisualBasic` namespace

Comment: Sorry i added wrong tag, i mean vbscript, i also add the code in my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All VBScript variables are Variants, but there are [subtypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). An empty/not initialized variable has the subtype Empty. The value of such a variable 'works' like 0 or "" in expressions:

```
>> Dim EmptyVar
>> WScript.Echo VarType(EmptyVar), TypeName(EmptyVar), 1 + EmptyVar, "a" & EmptyVar & "c"
>>
0 Empty 1 ac
>> WScript.Echo CStr(EmptyVar = 0), CStr(EmptyVar = "")
>>
True True
```

A string variable (initialized by a literal or a string expression) has the subtype String.
It may be empty - i.e. contain no characters - but such a beast is **not** of subtype Empty:

```
>> Dim NixStr : NixStr = ""
>> WScript.Echo VarType(NixStr), TypeName(NixStr), 1 & NixStr, "a" & NixStr & "c"
>>
8 String 1 ac
>>
```

The VBScript function [IsEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) checks whether a variable is empty/not initialized:

```
>> WScript.Echo CStr(IsEmpty(EmptyVar)), CStr(IsEmpty(NixStr))
>>
True False
```

That is why you should check the return value of [Inputbox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with IsEmpty() - did the user cancel/abort - **and** against "" - did the user try to feed "" to the program.

Answer (score -3):

Trim returns the string without ony spaces on the left or right. Eg, " hello world " will become "hello w world".

`isEmpty` returns a boolean. If the string is empty ("") it will return true, otherwise it will return false.

Comment: So if request.form("alias") is equal to "" what happens? it enter to the first if or the else?

Comment: @theLaw no, IsEmpty() returns true only if variable has not been initialized. If it's has been initialized with an empty string it returns false (also for Null it'll return false). It'll return true also if you set variable to Empty (but...ok...bad names...) but it's not an empty string (it represents an empty value).